# Is there a way to make @ModelAttribute dynamic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

For example, in this controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String save(
            @ModelAttribute("newInstance") MyClass newInstance) { . . . }
```

Is it possible to make the `@ModelAttribute` annotated parameter dynamic? I want to be able to use it for multiple objects, regardless of type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations are constants defined at compile time (which is why there is only a limited set of types you can use for an annotations methods/members).

It does not mean that they can't be dynamic though, you will just require some crafty work on your part (or another library's part).

You could create a small scripting language and have an expression as the parameter.  That way, the `String` value might not be dynamic, but what your language does with the expression contained within the `String` can be.

Luckily, you don't have to write your own small language, because Spring has already done that for you.  [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html).  I am not sure if SpEL is going to help you right here but it is worth a look.

Answer (score 4):

You could instantiate a model object dynamically via reflection and then manually trigger binding to get the desired result.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/add/{modelSelect}")
public String saveEntity(@PathVariable String modelSelect, WebRequest request){
    Object domainObject = //create object with your custom strategy using the modelSelect       
    WebRequestDataBinder binder = new WebRequestDataBinder(domainObject);
    binder.bind(request);
    //do something with the domain object
    return "/somePage";
}
```

This may also be usefull http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebRequestDataBinder.html